# htaccess - RewriteRules declared causing 404 errors

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

Not sure why my .htaccess file isn't doing what it is supposed to do here regarding mod_rewrite.

mod_rewrite is enabled and directory path has correct directives in place I believe.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/test>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Running apache2 on ubuntu 20.04

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test/_plugin/accounts/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/_plugin/accounts/(.*)$ /test/accounts/$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^test/accounts/(.*)$ /test/_plugin/accounts/$1 [L]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is:

- keep contents of `/test/_plugin/accounts/` and display that to rewrite URL to `/test/accounts/` where `/test/accounts/` directory doesn't actually exist.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Comment: 404 Not Found...I'm guessing because `/test/accounts/` doesn't actually exist.  Is there a way to copy contents from `/test/_plugin/accounts/` to `/test/accounts/` without `/test/accounts/` actually existing with rewrite?

Comment: What folder is this htaccess file located in?

Comment: it is located in the `/test/` folder

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've got it figured out now.  I took the `Indexes` directive out and that seemed to make things work.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/test>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and modified the .htaccess a bit:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test/_plugin/accounts/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^_plugin/accounts/(.*)$ /test/accounts/$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^accounts/(.*)$ /test/_plugin/accounts/$1 [L]
```